# ActionController::RoutingError for stylesheet in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I was tring out below scenario:

Approach 1: Created an resource using rails scaffold, coded all the functionality i.e. index, new, edit and delete functionality - everything is working fine.

Approach 2: Tried to create manually the controller and views for the same functionality with different name for the model created in approach 1. The functionality is working fine.

But i get an RoutingError as:

```
Started GET "/userwebmgmts/stylesheets/ctlCalendar.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-29 17:08:37 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/userwebmgmts/stylesheets/ctlCalendar.css"):
```

In Route.rb file:

added the entry for the newly created controller/view as: `get "userwebmgmts/index"`

Can anyone help tell why i am getting the error for the controller created manually  and not getting the error for the resources created using scaffold?

Thanks,
Sudhir C.N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark from the information you provided but...

Rails routes work in an order first a rack application checks the `/public/` folder in the root of your application.  If there is a matching file then it will load that.

> #### Rails 3.1
>
> If not it will load up the assets folder and create the pipe line and then check the application.css and application.js

Then it will load up the routes file and start ticking though your routes

If no route matches then you will get an exception thrown.

### Your Problem

Your problem probably comes from the fact that your css is in the wrong place

With your file structure

```
/userwebmgmts/stylesheets/ctlCalendar.css
```

You should have a link in the page header that looks like this

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/userwebmgmts/stylesheets/ctlCalendar.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

And the file should be located at

```
/public/userwebmgmts/stylesheets/ctlCalendar.css
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it worked. But my question is i have 4 css files under /public/stylesheets/*.css files. Why do i get routingerror for only one ctlCalendar.css file?

Comment: Also let me know what else information required to solve the issue?

Comment: i am using the rails version 3.0.9. Hence assets folder doesn't exists.

Comment: What worked?  I am guessing you get a routing error for only one because you spelled one wrong. Also please remember to up vote and accept the correct/good answers

Comment: I created the folder structure /public/userwebmgmts/stylesheets/ and placed the file ctlCalendar.css. I didn't get the routing error. But my question is: there are 4 stylesheets under /public/stylesheets/ for approach 1, but i am getting routingerror for only one stylesheet in apprach 2. Can i know the reason for this?

Comment: @sudhir what are the link lines in your header for your style sheets?

Comment: css link line is : <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>, there are 4 files, but getting routingerror for only one file css file